# Bezier curve middle does not follow pose

Tags: armature, bezier-curves, pose-mode

Bezier curve middle does not seem to follow pose. I have made two hooks, each connected to bones. The bezier curve is parented to the armature. What have I done wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the image I have moved the position of the hip. Everything else follows. If I rotate the bones that the hooks are attached to, they follow that movement, but still stuck in the middle

Comment: You probably need to hook the curve handles along with the curve vertex

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I have tried to look curve vertex up, but I am not sure what it means. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to hook the curve handles to the bones, along with the curve vertex.

If the handles are not hooked, only the end points of the curve will move, while it's shape appears to stay behind.

Enter *Edit Mode* on the curve, select both handles of each of the hooked vertex, and assign it to the corresponding *Hook* modifier.

[image: Assign Hook]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!